# jQuery Mobile collapsable menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to work on  amobile version of a website and need to design navigation menu with support for Submenus also. I did something but didnt get do it right How can i convert this into a nice navigation menu with support for sub-menus as well.

I have setup fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/T7QTF/1/.

Or what is the best `Nav` we can which will support sub-menu's also.

I am using following latest libraries

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script> 

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>

        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r">Page Two</a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r">Sub Page Page Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="search">Sub Page b </a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="search">Search</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>My Content..</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
         <h1>My Footer</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try nested collapsible sets because user can choose the menu item they want without redirecting to another page. So in page two sub pages are hidden inside collapsible. I don't suggest nested List views since it redirect when you click a single top most menu item. Then user need to click on back button or something. But with nested collectibles you can save space. And user saves time without navigating back to only see what are the sub menus are.

Here there is a collapsible example.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/listviews/

Comment: Yes Nested which is the last one seems to be an option but i cant find how we can move back to the previous menu option it just goes in forward direction you cant go back.

Comment: You need to add a back button there. The difference between collectibles and List menus is you can select sub menus(their headings) without clicking a top menu item and see it's subs and coming back and so on..